# What are the settings in the Gunicorn config file used by Google App Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, gunicorn

As mentioned in the [GAE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup), if "entrypoint" is not defined in app, App Engine will start a "default" Gunicorn server.

> If you do not specify an entrypoint for the Python 3 runtime, App Engine configures and starts the default Gunicorn web server.

But the question is what is this "default"? From the logs it seems to be referencing a `/config/gunicorn.py` but because App Engine is a restricted runtime, we are not able to browse and view this file.

We know that App Engine does not use all the [default settings defined by Gunicorn](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#worker-class), as App Engine uses `gthread` workers instead of the default `sync` workers. We would like to know the full Gunicorn settings so that we can understand our instances better, for example number of threads defined per worker, etc.

I understand that we can define custom settings for the Gunicorn server if we specify the entrypoint in app.yaml, but we want to also know what is the default settings App Engine uses / recommends.

Relevant Logs:

```
DEFAULT 2023-12-26T08:08:55.960190Z [serve] Running /bin/sh -c exec gunicorn main:app --workers 8 -c /config/gunicorn.py
DEFAULT 2023-12-26T08:08:56.381895Z [2023-12-26 08:08:56 +0000] [12] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
DEFAULT 2023-12-26T08:08:56.386398Z [2023-12-26 08:08:56 +0000] [12] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (12)
DEFAULT 2023-12-26T08:08:56.386547Z [2023-12-26 08:08:56 +0000] [12] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
```

Comment: You can use `--log-level=debug` to see all detail setting that applied.

Comment: In any case, use it for debug purpose, and do not design your app according to those parameters. Because it's Google Cloud (secret) sauce, it can be changed at any time, without any notice.

Comment: As mentioned by @guillaumeblaquiere, we can’t predict `Google cloud` settings. Unless `Google` is using a custom `gunicorn.py`, the default for workers might be 1 as mentioned in [this file](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-processes).

Comment: For configuring your `gunicorn`, [App Engine recommendations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#entrypoint_best_practices) suggest 8 workers for their F4\_1G image. The [gunicorn](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#how-many-workers) docs recommend (2 x $num\_cores) + 1 (17 in the F4\_1G image) as the default number of workers. But, only a certain number of workers can fit into memory of instance class, so you may need to use workers suggested by `app engine recommendation` docs if your app is non-trivial.

Comment: You write code to copy the contents of `/config/gunicorn.py` to the HTTP response body.

Answer (score 1):

You can download docker images of your app engine standard deployment like this:

```
docker pull us.gcr.io/<project-name>/app-engine-tmp/app/default/ttl-18h:latest
```

I think the `gunicorn.py` should be included with that so you can see all the settings.